# How do I have conditional copy statement in ARM template

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

I see some examples and answers how to do conditional copy but none seems to be flexible enough to have both number and sizes of disks to be flexible. My template expects parameter which identifies type of storage and size of disk separated by `-` like below

```
DataDiskArray: {
value: [
   "Standard_LRS-64",
   "Standard_LRS-1036"
 ] 
}
```

It works fine as long as I have at least one disk but I'm having trouble understanding how do I do that when there is no data disks needed at all like

```
DataDiskArray: {
value: [ ] 
}
```

I put `copy[]` statement into variable but it still being evaluated and fails

```
"dataDisks": {
            "copy": [
                {
                    "name": "dataDisks",
                    "count": "[if(equals(length(parameters('DataDiskArray')),0), 1, length(parameters('DataDiskArray')))]",
                    "input": {
                        "caching": "ReadWrite",
                        "diskSizeGB": "[split(parameters('DataDiskArray')[copyIndex('dataDisks')],'-')[1]]",
                        "lun": "[copyIndex('dataDisks')]",
                        "name": "[concat(parameters('VirtualMachineName'), '-DDisk', string(add(copyIndex('dataDisks'),1)))]",
                        "managedDisk": {
                            "storageAccountType": "[split(parameters('DataDiskArray')[copyIndex('dataDisks')],'-')[0]]"
                        },
                        "createOption": "Empty"
                    }
                }
            ]
```

Resource Deployment inside VM resource

```
"dataDisks": "[if(equals(length(parameters('DataDiskArray')),0),json('null'),variables('dataDisks'))]"
```

Comment: How about creating the data disk into a managed disk resource and copy it with your specific input and copy condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all, your variable declaration is wrong, it should be just this:

```
"variables": {
    "copy": [
        {
            "name": "blah" <<< name of the created variable
            <<ommited>>
        }
    ]
}
```

this happens because variables are always being evaluated, that being said, you just need to condition pretty much everything, or use a "proxy":

```
 "proxy": "[if(empty(parameters('DataDiskArray')), variables('fakearray'), parameters('DataDiskArray'))]"
 "fakearray": [
     "Standard_LRS-64"
 ]
```

and then you would use the same copy, but target the `proxy` variable, not the `datadiskarray` parameter. (you can drop the `if` statement as well). or you need `if` statement everywhere you try to access the `datadiskarray` parameter